# API call goes to catch, when it should be going to try

Tags: javascript, api, asynchronous, try-catch

I am trying to make a weather app, and when you search in the search bar, it searches the top 10 most related locations.

So everything works correctly at the start:

1. You search for a place e.g. Toronto
2. You click on Toronto, Ontario in the list of the 10 most relevant locations
3. You get the weather
4. (this is where the problem starts) When you search something again in the search bar, it will always go to the catch, and will be unable to successfully call the api

here is the code for index.js

```
import {classes, elements} from "./base"
import {timeConverter} from "./timeConverter";

import weather from "./models/weather";
import GeoCode from "./models/geocode";
import * as searchView from "./views/searchView";
import * as weatherView from "./views/weatherView";
import Weather from "./models/weather";

const state = {};

/**
 * SEARCH CONTROLLER
 */
// STACK OVERFLOW PROBLEM HERE
const searchController = async search => {

    // Checks if there is a value in the search bar
    if(search){
        
        // Reset the search bar
        elements.inputSearch.value = "";

        // Calculate the geocode for the given location
        const geocode = new GeoCode(search);
        console.log(geocode);
        try {
            await geocode.getLatLong();
            console.log(geocode);

            // List all the relevent locations on the UI
            geocode.locations.forEach(current => {

            // Render the results on the UI
            searchView.renderResults(current.display_name, current.lat, current.lon);
        })} catch(err){
            searchView.renderNoResults(search);
        } 
    }
}

/**
 * WEATHER CONTROLLER
 */
const weatherController = (location) => {
    console.log(location.weather.current);

    // Prepare UI for changes
    searchView.clearUI(classes.CWGuide);
    searchView.clearUI(classes.CWLocations);
    
    // Render the current Weather
    weatherView.renderCurrentWeather(location.weather.current);
}

/**
 * EVENT HANDLERS
 */

// topbar events
// search
elements.topBar.addEventListener("click", event => {
    if(event.target.matches(`${classes.confirmSearch}, ${classes.confirmSearch} *`)){
        let input = elements.inputSearch.value;
        searchController(input);
    }
});

// search: enter
window.addEventListener("keydown", e =>{
    if(e.key === "Enter" && elements.inputSearch === document.activeElement){
        let input = elements.inputSearch.value;
        searchController(input);
    }
});

// CW_locations events
// location
elements.CW.addEventListener("click", async event => {
    if(event.target.matches(`${classes.CWLocationsOption}, ${classes.CWLocationsOption} *`)){

        // Get weather data
        const location = new Weather(event.target.dataset.lat, event.target.dataset.lon);
        await location.getResults();

        // Call weather controller with weather data
        weatherController(location);
    }
})
```

this is my weather.js

```
import axios from "axios";

export default class Weather{
    constructor(lat, lon){
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lon = lon;
    }

    async getResults() {
        try {
            const key = "API key";
            const res = await axios(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${this.lat}&lon=${this.lon}&%20exclude=daily&appid=${key}&units=metric`);
            this.weather = res.data;
        }catch(error){
            alert(error);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the searchView.js file

```
import {classes, elements} from "../base";

export const renderResults = (name, lat, lon) => {

    // Prepare markups for use
    let containerMarkup = `
        <div class="CW_locations"></div>`
    let optionMarkup = `
        <div class="CW_locations_option" data-lat="${lat}" data-lon="${lon}">${name}</div>`

    // Check if CW already has the CW_locations div in it
    if(elements.CW.closest(classes.CWLocations)){

        // Add item
        document.querySelector(classes.CWLocations).insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", optionMarkup);
    }else{
        // Chance the guidance message
        document.querySelector(classes.CWGuide).textContent="Please choose the desired location below";

        // Add item
        elements.CW.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", containerMarkup);
        document.querySelector(classes.CWLocations).insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", optionMarkup);
    }
};

export const renderNoResults = name => {
    let markup = `
    <div class="CW_guide">Could not find a relevant location to ${name}</div>
    `
    elements.CW.innerHTML = markup;
}

export const clearUI = target => {
    document.querySelector(target).remove();
}
```

This is weatherView.js

```
import {classes, elements} from "../base";

export const renderCurrentWeather = (weather) => {
    console.log(weather.weather[0].description);
    let markup = `
    <div class="CW_wrapper">
    <div class="CW_city">Toronto, Ontario</div>
        <div class="CW_img">
            <div class="CW_temp_title">${weather.weather[0].description}</div>
            <img src="img/snow.svg" class="CW_image">
        </div>
        <div class="CW_info">
            <div class="info_date">July 17, 2020</div>
                <div class="info_content">
                    <div class="info_tab">
                        <div class="info_tab_title">Weather</div>
                        <div class="info_tab_section">
                            <div class="info_type">Temperature</div><div class="info_value">${Math.round(weather.temp)} °C</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="info_tab_section">
                            <div class="info_type">Feels like</div><div class="info_value">${Math.round(weather.feels_like)} °C</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="info_tab_section">
                            <div class="info_type">Wind</div><div class="info_value">${weather.wind_speed} m/s</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="info_tab_section">
                            <div class="info_type">Wind direction</div><div class="info_value">${weather.wind_deg} °</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="info_tab_section">
                            <div class="info_type">Humidity</div><div class="info_value">${weather.humidity} hPa</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="info_tab_section">
                            <div class="info_type">Pressure</div><div class="info_value">${weather.pressure} hPa</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="info_tab">
                        <div class="info_tab_title ">Clothing</div>
                        <div class="info_tab_section info_clothing">
                            <div class="info_type">Head</div><div class="info_value">Something that will cover yo ad asd asd asd adsaur ears asdasd asd asdasd asd  </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="info_tab_section">
                            <div class="info_type">Body</div><div class="info_value">a warm coat </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="info_tab_section">
                            <div class="info_type">Legs</div><div class="info_value">thick pants</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="info_tab_section">
                            <div class="info_type">Feet</div><div class="info_value">Preferrably boots</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="info_tab">
                        <div class="info_tab_title ">Message</div>
                        <div class="info_tab_section info_message">
                            <div class="info_message_txt"> al;sdmasdas dasd asdasdasdkj kjdkajs jkasjdk jaskd jaskldj klasdjkasljd</div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div
    `
    elements.CW.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",markup);
}
```

Comment: it's not that big of a deal, because I can just get another API key, I'm going to change it later. but sure

Comment: Well if it goes to catch what is the error in catch? Need to do some basic debugging to determine what the actual problem is and why it occurs. That error contains vital details. Note that `alert()` is a terrible debugging tool. log error to your browser dev tools console and inspect it there

Comment: What is the error, as captured by your catch?

Comment: This is the error: `TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null
    at Object.renderResults (searchView.js:23)
    at eval (index.js:64)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at _callee$ (index.js:61)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js:65)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js:303)
    at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (runtime.js:117)
    at step (index.js:27)
    at eval (index.js:27)`

Comment: So that indicates one of the querySelector() calls is returning null and gives you something to focus further debugging on. Looks like you only use `textContent` once in my quick glance through code so that really narrows it down